# User Query sort on custom field then name

Tags: sort, wp-user-query

I am trying to sort a list of attorneys (set up as Users) classified as founding members, members, and associates. Those classifications are stored in the attorney_title meta field.

I need them to sort by title (in this specific order, not alphabetically), then sort the attorneys alphabetically:

- Founding Members

  - Anthony
  - Bob
  - Carla
- Members

  - Andy
  - Barbara
  - Charles
- Associates

  - Anna
  - Brent
  - Cody

Currently I'm doing a query for founders, then a query for members, then a query for associates. But I figure there might be a sensible way to do it in one query. If the attorney titles were alphabetical then I could probably get it, but since they must be sorted in a specific order, I'm not getting it.

Comment: This is less about sorting and more about grouping. Multiple queries, or 2 large queries and them PHP computation to relate them is probably the way to go here.